# How can I optimize my recursive SPARQL query?

Tags: query-optimization, sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to extract buildings from Wikidata using a recursive SPARQL query but I keep getting query timeouts. Is there a way to circumvent this?

This is my current query, selecting all buildings with either a Freebase ID or a Google Knowledge Graph ID, and a Dutch label:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?building ?buildingLabel
WHERE {
  ?building p:P2671|p:P646 ?id;
            p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q41176;
            rdfs:label ?buildingLabel .
  FILTER(LANG(?buildingLabel) = 'nl') .
  FILTER (?building != ?buildingLabel) .
}
```

I've tried manually looking a few layers deep instead but, for some reason, I get no results for three or more layers deep even though those definitely exist. I've tried this using:

```
SELECT ?building
WHERE {
 ?building p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279 [p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279 [p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279 wd:Q41176]].
}
```

and using

```
SELECT ?building
WHERE {
 ?parent2 p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279 wd:Q41176.
 ?parent1 p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279 ?parent2.
 ?building p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279 ?parent1.
}
```

There are about 2.24 million buildings and about 18 million entities with either a Freebase ID or a Google Knowledge Graph ID on Wikidata. I've looked at [this guide](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/query_optimization) but couldn't quite figure out how to apply it to my query. I've also read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105123/how-can-i-avoid-timeout-on-a-sparql-query-on-wikidata) but, unfortunately, using multiple queries isn't really an option for me.

Comment: `p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279 [p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279` is not equivalent to `p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279*` as precendence of `*` is higher than `/` - if you want at most three hops in hierarchy, you should use `p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279?/wdt:P279?/wdt:P279?`

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to use the "recursive" property path to find things of type building *and also* types that are subclasses of buildings, your first query using `wdt:P279*` is right, while the later attempts at repeating the full `p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279` pattern won't match any data.

By simplifying the first query a bit I was able to get this to run (returning 96,297 results in 39s):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?building ?buildingLabel
WHERE {
  ?building p:P2671|p:P646 ?id;
            wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q41176 .
  ?building rdfs:label ?buildingLabel .
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?buildingLabel), "nl"))
}
```

Two notable changes:

- `p:P31/ps:P31` is replaced by `wdt:P31`, removing one join from the query.
- The second `FILTER` is unnecessary, as `?building` (a URI) and `?buildingLabel` (a string) are necessarily going to be unequal